# While running my program the chromium driver doesn't start

Tags: command-line, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

Running my program the terminal throws the following error

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:63762/devtools/browser/0e266bb1-5a0e-4403-be15-e114d23b155a
[0907/105719.182:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(128)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuControl.CreateCommandBuffer.
[0907/105721.137:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'ambient-light-sensor'.", source:  (0)
```

I did look at a few online forums and they suggested to go and delete lines 61 to 63 in
`/usr/bin/chromium?`
But the thing is that I have been unable to find it and suspect that it is a mainly linux thing while I am working on a Windows system.
I really don't know how to tackle this and every solution on the internet just confuses me more

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.